# Need to remove white line (borderWidth:0) when single pie slice in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How to remove/hide sliced line from pie chart when only one object with 100%? Issue in IE and Firefox.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Comment: You can set borderWidth to 1 and set its color to the same as the pie. It seems to solve the issue http://jsfiddle.net/vpqz0hsm/